# Forward websocket through Proxy VPN server

Tags: networking, websocket, server, tcp, proxy

So currently the entire system is set up as follows: 
Client -----> Google Cloud Compute Instance (VPN Proxy Server) ------> Actual Server.

The client can only access the Proxy server through its domain name. eg: abc.com 
The Actual Server has the WebSocket server running and open, I can access it through any device within LAN.

How will I go about forwarding the Client's '**ws://abc.com:9000**' WebSocket to the actual server's port 9090? 
I have access to only the VPN Server and Actual Server. Both of them are configured using Wireguard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx reverse proxy

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

stream {
  resolver 8.8.8.8;

  map $ssl_preread_server_name $selected_upstream {
    YOUR.WIREGUARD.WEBSITE.COM 127.0.0.1:10443;
    default 127.0.0.1:8443; # YOUR EXISTING HTTPS WEBSERVER ADDRESS
  }

  server {
    listen 443; # PORT WE WILL LISTEN ON
    proxy_pass $selected_upstream;
    ssl_preread on;
  }
}
```

source: https://www.martinkonicek.eu/en/blog/websocket-connection-to-wireguard